# Cannot connect to Cloud SQL read replica that is replicating from external master

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Following the documentation to configure external master replication:  https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/configure-external-master

I have created a First Generation read replica that is replicating from an external master.  But I cannot connect to the Cloud SQL read replica.  The documentation states you need to create a user account on the read replica.  Attempting to do this gives you `Operation not allowed for a read replica.`  And I see a `root` and `(anonymous)` user already but I cannot change their passwords.  I get the same error message `Operation not allowed for a read replica.`

See this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me where you found that _The documentation states you need to create a user account on the read replica_?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't say that, but how else do you connect to the read replica?  As you can see in the screenshot.  There's `(anonymous)` and `root` users that are authorized from `localhost`.  If you need to create users on the external master to propagate down to the read replica, I think there should be more clear messaging.
That sounds like a security limitation.  What if you don't want users connecting to both the master and read replica?

Comment: You should connect to the read replica with the `user` and `password` created in the Master external instance. I agree that maybe the message should be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to connect to cloud SQL replica by using 'root' user with no password. In the documentation they suggest you can add users to a replica, but if you try server gives you an error. You can add password to your root user though

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the docs regarding External Master configuration. Especially in:

> **[Before you begin](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/configure-external-master#before_you_begin)**
>
> - ...
> - You must have the external **IP address and port of the external master instance, and the username and password information** for the
>   replication user on the master instance.
> - ...

Also in [Requirements and Tips for Configuring Replication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/tips#operations):

> - The MySQL **settings of the master instance are propagated to the replica, including root password** and changes to the user table.
> - ......

To summarise, the user and password must be set in the Replication master and use those to connect to the read replica.